# Re-create tables of EF CodeFirst from command package manager console

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I use EF CodeFirst and would like to recreate tables in database using command line from package manager console, how to do that?

The problem is that while developing a EF CodeFirst models changes often and I delete tables in database manually and then EF recreate them on first run. To delete tables manually takes time and I think it should be a command which recreate tables from scratch in EF.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Update-Database -Target 0` to revert your database to it's initial state and then `Update-Database` to update your database to the latest version.

Comment: I'd suggest adding `-Force` to the end of that, assuming you've made modifications to the data since the last time you ran `Update-Database`.